# Why is the Hilbert scheme $ \operatorname{Hilb} ( n )_S $ a subscheme of a Grassmannian to determine?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, moduli-space

In the following link of Wikipedia : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_scheme , there is a short sentence in the paragraph : ***Construction***, which says :

> Grothendieck constructed the Hilbert scheme $ \operatorname{Hilb} ( n )_S =
>  \displaystyle \coprod_{P} \operatorname{Hilb} ( n , P )_S $ of $n$-dimensional projective space over a Noetherian scheme $S$ as a subscheme of a Grassmannian defined by the vanishing of various determinants.

Can you explain me in more detail why is the Hilbert scheme $\operatorname{Hilb} ( n )_S = \displaystyle \coprod_{P} \mathrm{Hilb} ( n , P )_S $ of $n$-dimensional projective space over a Noetherian scheme $S$ a subscheme of a Grassmannian defined by the vanishing of various determinants ? How to write this explicitly ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you looked for notes describing this on the internet? This construction is not too short (often 7-10 pages in written notes with preliminaries and a decent amount of detail), and reading the pre-existing notes on this subject will probably be more successful than waiting for someone to come type all of them out for you here.

Comment: @KReiser : Thank you.  :-) Yes, of course, i looked some notes describing this on the internet, but i never find any description of this subscheme by vanishing of various determinants. Can you help me please ?  :-)

Comment: Not directly related, but if you are interested by explicit description of Hilbert schemes, you should look the book by Nakajima on punctual Hilbert schemes where there are lot of details, very nice descriptions and links with physics, affine Lie algebras, singularities etc ... :-)

Comment: Thank you very much Nicolas.  :-) I tried to know clearly the answer of this question before attacking another one i posted here : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308932/how-to-calculate-mathrmhdg-2-bullet-mathcalh-mathrmilb-mat just a few moment before. Can you give me an answer to this question appearing in this link above, of mathoverflow ? Take a look to read it. :-) Thank you.  :-)

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet : Is the book that you mentionned in your comment above named : Lectures on Hilbert scheme of points on surfaces ?

Comment: Yes this is the name of the book. I don't know the immediate answer to your mathoverflow question, and I would probably need some time in order to make an answer, it's probably non trivial. There are probably expert in algebraic geometry who can answer, but if after a long time you get no answer I can try to think about it.

Comment: Thank you very much Nicolas.  :-)